# i want hook permission for my code in drupal 7 code is below

Tags: drupal-7

I created a module called 'add_site'. But when i go to module section in admin panel, there is no option to set permission for this module. therefore anonymous user can get access to this module as well. But I don't want anonymous user to get access to this module. Can you please help me how to set

```
my drupal .module code is here pls povide me the hook_permission code


<?php
// $Id: person.module

/**
 * implements hook_menu()
 */
function person_menu(){ 
    $items  = array();
    $items['person'] = array(
        'title' => "Person",
        'page callback' => "perso_personal_info", // after visit drupal6/person, person_personal_info() function is called
        'access callback' => true,  // must return true, otherwise it will not visible as menu item
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, // drupal's default menu type   
        'weight' => '10', // we want to display person link below in our nav menu
    );      
    return $items; // finally, do not forget to return $items array
}
function perso_personal_info(){
    $output = 'Name: Gaurav</br>';
    $output .= 'City: nanital </br>';
    $output .= 'Country: india </br>';
    return $output;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it

function person_permission(){
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  ); 
}